# Change Grails REST format /controller/<id>/<action>

Tags: grails

I messed around with this a bit yesterday and failed miserably.  I want to convert:

```
"/$controller/$action?/$id?"
```

To

```
#in psudo
"/$controller/$id?/$action?"
#ideal regex
"\/(\w+)(\/\d+)?(\/\w+)?"
```

The most obvious way failed `"/$controller/$action?/$id?"`

I can write the regex's to do it, but I am having trouble finding a way to using true regexs (I found [RegexUrlMapping](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.3/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/mapping/RegexUrlMapping.html) but could not find out how to use it), and also can't find documentation on how to assign a group to a variable.

My question is 2 parts:

1. How to I define a URL Resource with a true regex.
2. How to I bind a "group" to a variable. In other words if I define a regex, how do I bind it to a variable like $controller, $id, $action

I would also like to be able to support the .json notation /user/id.json

---

Other things I have tried, which I thought would work:

```
"/$controller$id?$action?"{
        constraints {
            controller(matches:/\w+/)
            id(matches:/\/\d+/)
            action(matches:/\/\w+/)
        }
    }
```

also tried:

```
"/$controller/$id?/$action?"{
        constraints {
            controller(matches:/\w+/)
            id(matches:/\d+/)
            action(matches:/\w+/)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The grails way to deal with this is to set

```
grails.mime.file.extensions = true
```

in `Config.groovy`.  This will cause Grails to strip off the file extension before applying the URL mappings, but make it available for use by [`withFormat`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/withFormat.html)

```
def someAction() {
  withFormat {
    json {
      render ([message:"hello"] as JSON)
    }
    xml {
      render(contentType:'text/xml') {
        //...
      }
    }
  }
```

For this you'd just need a URL mapping of `"$controller/$id?/$action?"`

I'm not aware of any way to use regular expressions in the way you want in the URL mappings, but you could get a forward mapping working using the fact that you can specify closures for parameter values that get evaluated at runtime with access to the other params:

```
"$controller/$a?/$b?" {
  action = { params.b ?: params.a }
  id = { params.b ? params.a : null }
}
```

which says "if `b` is set then use that as the action and `a` as the `id`, otherwise use `a` as the action and set `id` to `null`".  But this wouldn't give you a nice reverse mapping, i.e. `createLink(controller:'foo', action:'bar', id:1)` wouldn't generate anything sensible, you'd have to use `createLink(controller:'foo', params:[a:1, b:'bar'])`

**Edit**

A third possibility you could try is to combine the

```
"/$controller/$id/$action"{
    constraints {
        controller(matches:/\w+/)
        id(matches:/\d+/)
        action(matches:/\w+/)
    }
}
```

mapping with a complementary

```
"/$controller/$action?"{
    constraints {
        controller(matches:/\w+/)
        action(matches:/(?!\d+$)\w+/)
    }
}
```

using negative lookahead to ensure the two mappings are disjoint.

Comment: @Nix If you have a mapping of `"$controller/$id?/$action"` then `/user/list` will not work (well, it wouldn't set the `action` parameter so it would call whatever is the default action of the `UserController`, passing "list" as the `id` parameter value).

Comment: I still find this absolutely shocking... as for reverse mappings... Couldn't I add a dummy mapping(`$controller/$id?/$action?`) to be able to leverage reverse mappings ?

Comment: @Nix I've added another possibility if you want to give it a try.

Comment: The only thing this doesn't support is doing `<controller>/1.json` versus `<controller>/1/show.json` could probably work around it.  But def a better REST URL structure then the OOB solution.